# JS Toggle Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck on this.  I have an ajax function posting to php.  The post function is working fine.  I just want css to toggle on and off with each click while posting with each click.

When I click the '.fav-btn' button the first time I want 'fav-h' to be added to the class for styling. Also post to the php script.

When I click the '.fav-btn' button the second time I want 'fav-h' to be removed and button returns to original style.  Also post again to the php script.

I have tried various things including the .removeclass.   My code is below, I am not sure how to get the fav-h class style to be removed on the second click.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        var pageID = <?php echo $pageID  ?>; 
  var user_id = <?php echo $user_id ?>; 

        $('.fav-btn').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('fav-h');
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"../ajax.php",
    data: { act: 'fav', pageID: pageID, user_id: user_id },
                success: function(){
                }
            });
        });
});

$(document).ready(function(){ 
        var pageID = <?php echo $pageID  ?>; 
  var user_id = <?php echo $user_id ?>; 

        $('.fav-btn fav-h').click(function(){
            $('.fav-btn fav-h').removeClass('fav-h');    
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"../ajax.php",
    data: { act: 'fav', pageID: pageID, user_id: user_id },
                success: function(){
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to just have one block of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var pageID = <?php echo $pageID  ?>; 
    var user_id = <?php echo $user_id ?>; 

    $('.fav-btn').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('fav-h');
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"../ajax.php",
            data: { act: 'fav', pageID: pageID, user_id: user_id },
            success: function(){}
        });
    });
});
```

***PS:** your code was not working because you used `$('.fav-btn fav-h')`:*

```
<div class="fav-btn">
    <fav-h></fav-h>   <!-- This is what this selector leads to -->
</div>
```

*instead of the correct selector `$('.fav-btn.fav-h')`:*

```
<div class="fav-btn fav-h"></div>   <!-- Found the right one! -->
```

Comment: Thanks blex! Worked like a charm. I now see why I was having issues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is the same ajax call either way. You can probably just bind to the button once. Also, you might want to only update the class if the post was successful.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var pageID = <?php echo $pageID  ?>; 
    var user_id = <?php echo $user_id ?>; 

    $('.fav-btn').on('click', function(){
        var $t = $(this);
        $t.addClass('fav-saving');
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"../ajax.php",
            data: { act: 'fav', pageID: pageID, user_id: user_id },
            success: function(){
               $t.toggleClass('fav-h');
            },
            complete: function(){
               $t.removeClass('fav-saving');
            }
        });
    });
});
```